# Highlight indent level

Tags: lists, indentation

I am writing a reference document that contains a lot of nested lists. In order to highlight the indentation level of each list element, I would like to draw a subtle line in each level of identention in every list. In my mind it looks something like that:

[image: quick_example]

The closest analogue of such thing, I can remember, is an `algorithmicx` code sample:

[image]

But I don't know how to implement this with a list; would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172981/pseudo-code-with-vertical-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED SOLUTION (takes guesswork out of parameter selection)

With this revision, the guesswork is removed from the process, which is accomplished by forcing uniformity across the nested lists with `topsep`, `parsep`, and `itemsep`.  Instead, one must just specify 9 well understood parameters, as well as the colors of each bar.

```
\tpset=2pt\relax% uniform \topset
\psep=2pt\relax% uniform \parsep
\itsep=2pt\relax% uniform \itemsep
\rlthk=2pt\relax% Colorbar thickness
\def\fixlm{20pt}% Fixed indent per itemize level
\def\bulhwd{2.29pt}% Half Width of "bullet"; controls L/R shift of colorbars
\def\botscale{1.0}% controls vertical extent of bottom of colorbar
\def\topscale{1.0}% controls vertical extent of top of colorbar
\def\mybullet{$\bullet$}% bullet of itemized list
```

One of the tricks here is that `label*` adds the current label onto (*i.e.*, to the right of) the label from the next higher level.  Therefore, placing a bullet in the level 1 label makes a bullet show up on the left side of the level 2 label, and so forth.  To avoid this, I created `\bul[]` which will only print a bullet if no optional argument is passed.  Thus, I just make sure that the labels in levels 2, 3, 4, etc. start with an optional argument (here given as `[x]`), in order to nullify the trailing bullet from the prior level.  Neat!

In the MWE below, I demonstrate the result for two separate sets of parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\newlength\rlthk
\newlength\psep
\newlength\tpset
\newlength\itsep
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%USER PARAMETERS
\tpset=2pt\relax% uniform \topset
\psep=2pt\relax% uniform \parsep
\itsep=2pt\relax% uniform \itemsep
\rlthk=2pt\relax% Colorbar thickness
\def\fixlm{20pt}% Fixed indent per itemize level
\def\bulhwd{2.29pt}% Half Width of "bullet"; controls L/R shift of colorbars
\def\botscale{1.1}% controls vertical extent of bottom of colorbar
\def\topscale{1.1}% controls vertical extent of top of colorbar
\def\mybullet{$\bullet$}% bullet of itemized list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\rl[1][black]{\textcolor{#1}{%
  \rule[-\allseps]{\rlthk}{%
  \dimexpr\allseps-.3\baselineskip+\topscale\baselineskip+\topscale\psep+\topscale\tpset}}}
\newcommand\hs[1]{\hspace{#1}}
\newcommand\bul[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\mybullet\fi}
\def\offlm{\dimexpr\bulhwd-0.5\rlthk\relax}
\def\modlm{\dimexpr\leftmargin-\bulhwd-.5\rlthk\relax}
\def\allseps{\dimexpr\tpset+\psep-.9\baselineskip+\botscale\baselineskip+\itemsep}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label*=\bul,
  labelwidth=\fixlm,topsep=\tpset, parsep=\psep, itemsep=\itsep}
\setlist[itemize,2]{
   label*=[x]\smash{           \rl[red]\hs{\modlm}}\bul,
  leftmargin=\fixlm,topsep=\tpset, parsep=\psep, itemsep=\itsep}
\setlist[itemize,3]{
   label*=[x]\smash{\hs{\offlm}\rl[blue]\hs{\modlm}}\bul,
  leftmargin=\fixlm,topsep=\tpset, parsep=\psep, itemsep=\itsep}
\setlist[itemize,4]{
   label*=[x]\smash{\hs{\offlm}\rl[green]\hs{\modlm}}\bul,
  leftmargin=\fixlm,topsep=\tpset, parsep=\psep, itemsep=\itsep}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item A1
\item A2
  \begin{itemize}
  \item B1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item C1 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item D1 
      \item D2
      \end{itemize}
    \item C2
    \end{itemize}
  \item B2
  \item B3
  \end{itemize}
\item A3
\end{itemize}
\noindent\hrulefill
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%USER PARAMETERS
\tpset=1pt\relax% uniform \topset
\psep=1pt\relax% uniform \parsep
\itsep=1pt\relax% uniform \itemsep
\rlthk=4pt\relax% Colorbar thickness
\def\fixlm{30pt}% Fixed indent per itemize level
\def\bulhwd{5.7pt}% Half Width of "bullet"; controls L/R shift of colorbars
\def\botscale{1}% controls vertical extent of bottom of colorbar
\def\topscale{1}% controls vertical extent of top of colorbar
\def\mybullet{\raisebox{-3pt}{\Huge$\bullet$}}% bullet of itemized list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item A1
\item A2
  \begin{itemize}
  \item B1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item C1 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item D1 
      \item D2
      \end{itemize}
    \item C2
    \end{itemize}
  \item B2
  \item B3
  \end{itemize}
\item A3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (requires parameter specification)

Because parameters like topsep, parsep and itemsep change, by default, with each level of itemization, the parameters that govern the color bar placement need fitting.  However, this solution is simpler to understand than the full solution given above.

So, there's a little guesswork with the parameters at each level, but not so bad.  Once the parameters are determined for each level, it works with just the normal `itemize` environment syntax.

EDITED for color

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\def\rlthk{2pt}
\newcommand\rl[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-#2pt]{\rlthk}{#3\baselineskip}}}
\newcommand\hs[1]{\hspace{#1pt}}
\newcommand\bul[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1$\bullet$\fi}
\begin{document}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label*=\bul}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label*=[x]\smash{        \rl[red]  {14.5}{2.9}\hs{18.9}}\bul}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label*=[x]\smash{\hs{1.4}\rl[blue] {10.5}{2.2}\hs{15.4}}\bul}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label*=[x]\smash{\hs{1.2}\rl[green]{09.0}{1.9}\hs{13.8}}\bul}
\begin{itemize}
\item A1
\item A2
  \begin{itemize}
  \item B1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item C1
      \begin{itemize}
      \item D1
      \item D2
      \end{itemize}
    \item C2
    \end{itemize}
  \item B2
  \item B3
  \end{itemize}
\item A3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works just great, but with only one exeption: if the ident item has more than one line, a gap in the highlighting occurs: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/dvgcwyfatsch0lf/bofxisdp.png I can't figure out how it may be handled.

Comment: @TeXNewbie Problem confirmed.  Let me give it some thought.

Comment: @TeXNewbie  Using my revised solution, right before the multi-line `\item`, set `\def\botscale{2}` or some appropriate value.  After that `\item`, reset it to the default value: `\def\botscale{1.1}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I just ran into the same issue. Manually resetting `botscale` is a no-go for me, since I have hundreds of bullets in my document. Can it be done automatically?

Comment: I'm sorry @Mew, I know of no way to automate it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'd like to think nothing is impossible, but I don't know any TeX. Can you explain what the fundamental issue is? Perhaps other can help with the TeX code if they knew the issue, and if it's merely an algorithmic thing, perhaps I can come with a solution in a scripting language I do know. What data do(n't) we have access to, to solve this?

Comment: In essence, @Mew, the color bar depth is set at the invocation of the `\item`.  The problem is that, as of the `\item` invocation, one has no idea how long the actual text of the `\item` will be (whether it will fit on one line or extend to many).  To try to force `\item` to know what follows its invocation goes completely counter to how `\item` is implemented, both here as well as in the standard implementations.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Would it be possible to, instead of *immediately* drawing something at an `\item`, save a tuple `(indent level, y coordinate)` to a per-itemize list, and then draw lines from bullet to bullet using that list *after* having run through the itemize?

Comment: While anything is possible @Mew, saving coordinates and acting upon them at a later time would involve a complete reinterpretation of what an `\item` is.  It is more than what my simple approach offers.

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible solution where `tikzmark` is utilized here and `\VerticalLine` is defined that takes 3 arguments defined in the code as remarks.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3in,top=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,enumitem}
%
\setlist{nosep,before=\vspace{\baselineskip},after=\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\tikzmarkA}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,] \node[xshift=2pt] (#1) {};}

\newcommand\VerticalLine[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = top mark
    % #3 = bottom mark
\draw[#1] 
(#2)  --  (#2 |- #3);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$] indent level one
\item[$\bullet$] indent level one
\item[\tikzmarkA{a1}$\bullet$] indent level one
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[$\bullet$] indent level two
    \item[$\bullet$] indent level two
    \item[\tikzmarkA{a2}$\bullet$] indent level two
          \begin{itemize}
          \item[$\bullet$] indent level three
          \item[$\bullet$] indent level three
          \item[\tikzmarkA{a3}$\bullet$] indent level three
                \begin{itemize}
                 \item[$\bullet$] indent level four
                 \item[$\bullet$] indent level four
                 \item[\tikzmarkA{a4}$\bullet$] indent level four
                \end{itemize}
           \end{itemize}
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\VerticalLine[ultra thick,gray]{a1}{a4}
\VerticalLine[ultra thick,blue]{a2}{a4}
\VerticalLine[ultra thick,red]{a3}{a4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A minor improvement might be to define a `\newlint` which uses the `before` and `after` keys of `enumitem` to automatically add the `\tikzmark` at the start and end of a list and add the appropriate draw commands at the end of the top level list. I haven't tried it so not sure that there are not complications with this approach.  Also, there are issues if the lists span more than one page.

Comment: Yeah, the tikzpicture is limited to one page and this is recently commented in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212863/34618. That is why the proposal uses color lines so that manually page break in such case may help, IMHO.